# How to move to First viewController from last View controller among multiple view controllers

Tags: iphone, viewcontroller

Hii...i am new to iPhone programming..can anybody help me out please...!!
I have multiple viewControllers..in First ViewController called HomeViewController i called the method [self presentModalViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES]; in a IBAction for aboutButton to move to AboutViewController
and in the AboutViewController i called the method [self presentModalViewController:ContactUsViewController animated:YES]; to move to that view controller and one more method [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; to go back to HomeViewController.

in the 3rd, ContactUSViewController i called the method [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];to go back to the AboutViewController..and i want to go directly to HomeViewController from here(ContactUsViewController).i used [self presentModalViewController:homeViewController animated:YES]; but its not working...

How to do that...?

Thank u..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [doco](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) for *dismissModalViewControllerAnimated*:

> If you present several modal view
>   controllers in succession, and thus
>   build a stack of modal view
>   controllers, calling this method on a
>   view controller lower in the stack
>   dismisses its immediate child view
>   controller and all view controllers
>   above that child on the stack. When
>   this happens, only the top-most view
>   is dismissed in an animated fashion;
>   any intermediate view controllers are
>   simply removed from the stack.

So from your *ContactUsViewController* you need to call *dismissViewControllerAnimated* on the *HomeViewController*. You can access that view controller through *parentViewController* property.  So your code in the dismissAction for the *ContactUsViewController* is:

```
- (IBAction)dismissAction:(id)sender
{
    // get your parent (ie AboutViewController)
    UIViewController * parent = self.parentViewController;

    // get its parent (ie HomeViewController)
    [parent.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

There might be a better way of getting to your *HomeViewController*, but for your shallow stack of view controllers, this should be fine (I tried this out and it worked).

Comment: @macharlarakesh If there is something specific about this answer that you need clarifying, leave a comment here.

Comment: @macharlarakesh Glad to hear it :).  You can indicate the answer was helful by clicking the "accept answer" tick right under the vote number on the left hand side.