# Pop to the main view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

In my app I've 2 view controller that they appears by using a modal transition, now I developed the 3rd view controller and I put a button to go back to the main view controller, but how I can go back to the main view controller?
I tried with this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

but with this code I go back to the 2nd view controller. How I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Provide some code or explain well yout question

Comment: @iPatel that will only work if he had used a `UINavigationController` but he used modal presentation for the views.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229755/dismissing-multiple-modal-view-controllers-at-once

Comment: @Raon: which code do you need? It's an interface doubt... If you like I can post here some code, but i think it's not useful...

Comment: @iPatel: I will try to read your suggested page, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first modal presented the second modal, the following should work:

```
__weak UIViewController *vcThatPresentedCurrent = self.presentingViewController;

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    [vcThatPresentedCurrent dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this....

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController
 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Let me know if you have any problem.**