# Dismissing 2 modal dialogs at once?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

My rootviewcontroller in my iPad app presents a modal viewcontroller through `[self presentModalViewController:... animated:YES]` (lets call it ViewControllerA).

At some point, ViewControllerA itself presents a `MFMailComposeViewController` via `[self presentModalViewController:... animated:YES]`.

In the delegate method `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` I want to dismiss BOTH of the controllers, the `MFMailComposeViewController` AND ViewControllerA.

But no matter what i try (`[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`, `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`, calling dismiss twice), ONLY the `MFMailComposeViewController` is dismissed, but ViewControllerA stays visible.

I already found this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229755/dismissing-multiple-modal-view-controllers-at-once) and this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105855/how-to-move-to-first-viewcontroller-from-last-view-controller-among-multiple-vie), but the suggested solutions don't seem to work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried dismissing without animation?

Comment: No change, only the mail dialog disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem dismissing multiple modal views.
Probably you are getting the warning:

> Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress

The solution is to dismiss the first view without animation and then dismiss the other one. The last one can be dismissed using animation, there's no problem.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

            if (![[self modalViewController] isBeingDismissed])
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        default:
            break;    
    }
}
```